# Google App Engine Logging: Filter Based on HTTP Header

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

In the Google App Engine logs, is there a way to filter logging information based on the HTTP Request headers?

I don't even think there is a way to view the HTTP request headers in the logs, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default, but you can log them yourself.

Make sure you add some unique keyword so you can filter for it in the log viewer.

Comment: Unique keyword? What do you mean, add it to where?

Comment: Just add it to your log string.